# when i install ssl certificate in my website please tell me how to Redirect http to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, server, scripting

I try using .htaccess but its not working 
My code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mosaicwebsolution.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your virtual host, this is the easiest way:

```
Redirect permanent / https://mosaicwebsolution.com/
```

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mosaicwebsolution.com
    ServerAlias www.mosaicwebsolution.com

    Redirect permanent / https://www.mosaicwebsolution.com/
</VirtualHost>
```